# Maven verifier intergration tests don't find artifact under test

Tags: java, maven, integration-testing

I have a maven project ([github](https://github.com/mikesamuel/fences-maven-enforcer-rule)) that uses the Maven integration test [verifier](https://maven.apache.org/plugin-developers/plugin-testing.html#maven-verifier) extensively.

The tests refer to the project I'm testing.  For example, this [pom](https://github.com/mikesamuel/fences-maven-enforcer-rule/blob/master/src/test/resources/test-banned-use-in-transitive-dependency-project/pom.xml) does:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.1</version>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <!-- My project which customizes the plugin. -->
          <groupId>com.google.security</groupId>
          <artifactId>fences-maven-enforcer-rule</artifactId>
          <version>1.2-beta-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      ...
```

Where that dependency is to relative path ../../../../../pom.xml.

Then my [junit test](https://github.com/mikesamuel/fences-maven-enforcer-rule/blob/master/src/test/java/com/google/security/fences/FencesMavenEnforcerRuleTest.java) uses a `Verifier` to run the integration test.

```
// testProjectName is the basename of the directory
// containing the POM above.

File testDir = ResourceExtractor.simpleExtractResources(
    getClass(), "/" + testProjectName);

Verifier verifier = new Verifier(
    testDir.getAbsolutePath(),
    null, debug == Debug.VERBOSE, true /* forkJvm */);
// Clean up after previous runs.
verifier.deleteArtifacts("test");
Result goalResult = Result.PASS;
try {
  verifier.executeGoal("verify");
} catch (@SuppressWarnings("unused") VerificationException ex) {
  goalResult = Result.FAIL;
}
```

I can test this by doing `mvn install -DskipTests=true && mvn test` but that is less than ideal, because if I ever change code without reinstalling, I end up running tests against an out-of-date version, and because someone downloading the project for the first time can't just do `mvn test`.

Is there some way to tweak the POM or the junit TestCase so that the dependency is on the classes that were just compiled to `target/classes`?

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. Is `fences-maven-enforcer-rule` the artifact that you want to be present during the tests? Why declare the `maven-enforcer-plugin`? Could you expand on what it is you want to do, what it is you are doing and what is the problem?

Comment: @Tunaki, Good question.   My project (`fences-maven-enforcer-rule`) defines a custom [`EnforcerRule`](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-api/writing-a-custom-rule.html).  I'm testing the interaction between that rule, the enforcer plugin, and various configurations.

Comment: Wait, so you're saying that `fences-maven-enforcer-rule` can't access classes that are inside the project being built? What is the problem?

Comment: The POM above is for an integration test that is defined at `src/test/resources/test-banned-use-in-transitive-dependency-project/pom.xml`.  It configures `fences-maven-enforcer-rule` which is defined in `pom.xml`.

Comment: I understand that but what is the problem?

Comment: This sounds like a case for [maven-invoker-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/) instead of testing harness / verifier...if i don't mistaken...

Comment: @Tunaki, the problem is that I would like someone to be able to check out the project normally and run the tests (`git clone ...; cd fences-maven-enforcer-rule; mvn test`) but that does not work.

Comment: @khmarbaise, I'm horribly ignorant of the invoker plugin.  How does that allow using an artifact during phase verify?  And can one express negative tests?

Comment: @MikeSamuel You can run any phase within an invoker test also you define your own artifacts etc. For example [here](https://github.com/khmarbaise/uptodate-maven-plugin/tree/master/src/it) or [here](https://github.com/khmarbaise/iterator-maven-plugin/tree/master/src/it) and of course [here](https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin/tree/master/src).

Comment: @khmarbaise, but if the invoker test is run during the verify phase then there's still a dependency cycle, no?

Comment: @MikeSamuel Not that i see it..You create your artifact which is installed into `it-repo` located under `target` and the invoker will start an other instance of Maven which ran the it's ...so i don't see a problem..

Comment: BTW: What comes to my mind. Take a look here: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/enforcer/trunk/enforcer-rules/src/test/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/enforcer/ReactorModuleConvergenceTest.java?revision=1624846&view=markup

Comment: @khmarbaise, thanks much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either build and install the depenendy before you built the dependend project or both have to be part of the same reactor build. I think it does not work if it is in the same module (at least not with an artifact dependency, the test classes are automatically on the test class path - but the plugin might not load from there).

Comment: So it might be possible to create an aggregating POM and run the tests as part of its verify stage?

Comment: I think you can have a maven project with a module which builds your rules and a second module which contain the IT for them.

Comment: Ok, so I would verify by running the verify stage of the aggregating project, and the first module would be the artifact that I'd push to maven central.  Fair enough.

Comment: I think you can even enable `installAtEnd` attribute of the installer-plugin, then the build of the reactor will only install the artifacts when the IT suceeds.

Comment: Ah.  I didn't know installAtEnd was a thing.  I'll look into that, thanks.